# Unwanted lines appearing between semi-transparent elements in PDF output (generated with puppeteer)

Tags: pdf, svg, image-processing, puppeteer, chromium

I've been working on a node project with puppeteer.js for the last few months, but I have just started to use transparency in PDF files and have come across a real head scratcher...

### What am I trying to achieve?

3 horizontally adjoined, semi transparent divs, rendered as part of a pdf via puppeteer.

### What's the problem?

In html they display as expected. But in PDF a faint line appears between elements which I believe is to do with "stitching". I'm aware that this wont show in print, but I want to get rid of on screen. This is a mock up of some simple content which shows the behaviour I'm experiencing:

[image]

### What have I tried?

- Experimenting with Puppeteer params (antialiasing, flattening, color
  flags like -webkit-print-color-adjust) - [Result: no change]
- SVG elements with transparent background. [Result: lines still
  appear]
- A single div using a linear gradient with 3 block colors. [Result: Works when viewed in Acrobat, but has the weird effect in chrome where elements shift slightly to the right (pictured: top row - single div with linear gradient. Bottom row - black boxes used here as a guide for assessing alignment)].

[image]

- SVG elements using a linear gradient. [Result: Same as above]
- Flattening the pdf [Result: This does solve the problem, but degrades
  the quality of the rest of the image, therefore not suitable]

I'm finding it difficult to find a solution as I'm not really sure where the behaviour is emanating from (the PDF, puppeteer, browser?). If anybody has any ideas, I'd be very grateful!

Thanks

Comment: Showing the code that produces the problem as a [mcve] makes it a lot easier to help.

Comment: @KJ This doesn't seem like an edge aliasing issue to me. It seems more like a bug in the Chrome's PDF renderer.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem? I'm stuck with this